# Maximum of rectangle in triangle

Tags: derivatives

We have triangle ABC, AB=13cm AC=14cm and BC=15cm. On AC we put a K then AK=x(cm) and we create a rectangle KLMN that is in ABC. Find x for the area of rectangle KLMN is maximum.
Sorry for my English writing.

Comment: Sorry I cannot post the photo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The maximum rectangle area occurs when the midpoints of two of the
>   sides of the triangle were joined to make a side of the rectangle and
>   its area is thus 50% or half of the area of the triangle or 1/4 of the
>   base times height.

Proof : http://mathcountsnotes.blogspot.in/2013/05/the-largest-rectangle-inscribed-in-any.html

Hence, at this point of time we know that `x` can be 6.5, 7 or 7.5  .

Since , `K` is on `AC` , which is part of the rectangle `KLMN`  . Thus ,

```
x = 7
```

Comment: Sorry can I get the answer using derivative?

Comment: You want steps / proof ? Refer the link .